# Angular material stepper won't compile during ng serve

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-stepper

I'm new to angular material design, I'm using the angular cli to do my development.

I have been stuck on this for several hours, is it a bug with the latest version of angular material design?

I have:

- removed my package-lock.json
- deleted node_modules
- npm installed

and I get the following error doing an ng serve:

```
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 1.82 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 670 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 169 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 339 kB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-10-25T23:30:59.574Z - Hash: 715bbfd073a15e95d490 - Time: 10021ms

ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/stepper.d.ts:31:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (@angular/material/stepper) which declares MatStepper has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

31 export declare class MatStepper extends CdkStepper implements AfterContentInit {
                        ~~~~~~~~~~

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
```

My package.json is:

```
  "name": "main",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1002.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

my app.module.ts is:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatStepper } from '@angular/material/stepper';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { SearchComponent } from './search/search.component';
import { CreateComponent } from './create/create.component';
import { FormationsComponent } from './formations/formations.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    SearchComponent,
    CreateComponent,
    FormationsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatStepper,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: import "MatStepperModule" not "MatStepper"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/api

```js
import {MatStepperModule} from '@angular/material/stepper';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are importing `MatStepper` but stepper is a module, so `import MatStepperModule` in your app module:

```
import {MatStepperModule} from '@angular/material/stepper';
```

[Reference](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/api).